# CUDA 128 bytes read in a single instruction

Tags: memory, optimization, cuda

I am new to CUDA and currently optimize an existing application for molecular dynamics. What it does is that it takes array of double4 with coordinates and computes forces based on the neighborlist. I wrote a kernel with the following lines:

```
double4 mPos=d_arr_xyz[gid];
while(-1!=(id=d_neib_list[gid*MAX_NEIGHBORS+i])){
Calc(gid,mPos,AA,d_arr_xyz,id);i++;
}
```

then Calc takes d_arr_xyz[id] and calculates force. That gives 1 read of double4 + 65 reads of (int +double4) inside every call of Calc (65 is average number of neighbors (not equal to -1) in d_neib_list for each particle).

Is it possible to reduce those reads? Neighborlists for different particles, i.e. d_arr_xyz[gid] and d_arr_xyz[id] do not correalte, so I cannot use shared memory for the block of threads to cache d_arr_xyz.

What I see is that if somehow to load the whole list int*MAX_NEIGHBORS into shared memory in one or few large transactions, that will remove 65 separate reads of int.

So the question is: is it possible to do it so that those 65 reads of int will be translated into several large transactions. I read in the documentation that reads can be even 128 bytes long. What exactly should I write so that assembler will make 1 large call?

Update:

Thank you for your replies. From the answer from user talonmies below, I changed the code replacing dimensions x and y for the neighbors matrix. Now consecutive threads load consecutive int[gid], I guess that may result in a 128 byte read. The program works 8% faster.

Comment: If you have `N` particles and `P`cores, then, if each core is assigned a number of `N/P` particles, you could probably save some global memory transactions if you store the neighborhood information of each particle into shared memory. Have also a look at [Accelerating molecular dynamics simulations using GPUs with CUDA](ftp://btf.informatik.uni-bonn.de/pub/outgoing/IGD-Best-Paper-Award/2009/Articles/SR2008_g07a04.pdf), Section 5. Just grasp the main concepts and take into account that this papers deals with a very old architecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All memory transactions are issued (where possible) on a *per warp* basis. So the 128 byte transaction you are asking about is when all 32 threads in a warp issue a memory load instruction which can be serviced in a single "coalesced" transaction. A single thread can't issue large memory transactions, only a warp of 32 threads can, and only when the memory coalescing requirements of whichever architecture you run the code on can be satisfied.

I couldn't really follow your description of what you code is actually doing, but from first principles alone, the answer would appear to be no.